# Awake Method not starting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to use the Awake method without attaching it to an object, but it never initializes the class. It was supposed to initialize the class so that it could run an OnEnable method that added a subscriber to an event, but it did nothing. The only thing that works is attaching the script to a game object, but I don't want to do that, I tried changing the acmes modifier from private to protected virtual and a bunch more...

This is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementAnimationParameterControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator animator;

    private void Awake()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        EventHandler.MovementEvent += SetAnimationParameters;

        Debug.Log("Enable. Im running, its not me");
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        EventHandler.MovementEvent -= SetAnimationParameters;
        Debug.Log("Im running its not me");
    }

    private void SetAnimationParameters(float xInput, float yInput, bool isWalking)
    {
        animator.SetFloat(Settings.xInput, xInput);
        animator.SetFloat(Settings.yInput, yInput);
        animator.SetBool(Settings.isWalking, isWalking);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a Unity question. You are more likely to get useful answers if you tag it properly (say `unity`)

Comment: While @DekuDesu offers a very detailed explanation below, what I have to say is that, when working with unity, you NEED to work with GameObjects when in need of the MonoBehaviour methods. So, you probably need to change your logic here. Adding another GameObject as a container for the script is usually the best way to go.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! `unityscript` is or better was a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now! Your script is clearly `c#`!

Answer (score 2):

> It was supposed to initialize the class so that it could run an OnEnable method that added a subscriber to an event, but it did nothing. The only thing that works is attaching the script to a game object

When you create a class that inherits from [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) (Aka a 'Unity Script'. You're creating a script that allows the use of certain functions at runtime, such as `OnEnable` and `OnAwake` among others.

It might not seem too intuitive, but `MonoBehaviour` actual inherits indirectly from `GameObject`. The reason for this is because `GameObject` is the "target" of all of these methods like `Update()` for example.

Without an actual `GameObject` for your `MonoBehavior` to access it's properties at runtime, your script wont do anything.

The best example would be from your code.

Take the `OnAwake()` method for example

```cs
private void Awake()
{
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}
```

What this method does is set the field `animator` to the reference of `Animator`. That reference is found using the inherited method called `GetComponent`. Get component is an inherited method from the `MonoBehaviour` class, which like a russian nesting doll, is inherited from `GameObject`.

So what you're really doing is saying "hey GameObject that this script is attached to, please give me your Animator component, if you have one."

This is where we see the issue at hand, that without an actual `GameObject` to access none of the methods like `OnAwake()` or even the method calls contained within will work, since they all(or most) come from `GameObject` not actually from `MonoBehavior`.

There is also another major obstacle to overcome specifically with the events like `OnEnable()`, `OnAwake()`, `Start()` etc.. This issue comes from how Unity processes scripts during runtime. Only scripts with a actual `GameObject` is ever scheduled to have it's components scripts to run.

Think of it like a big pile of paper work on some body's desk. This big pile of paperwork consists of all of the scripts on all gameobjects in the scene. Unity has to pull a sheet of paperwork(a script) from the pile, run it's contents, and put it in the done pile on the opposite side of the desk. With this analogy, a script that doesn't have any attached `GameObject`, would be a sheet a paper with no name on it. Unity will look at this paper and say "This doesn't even have a name on it, I'm not even going to look at it" and then proceeds to throw it in the trash because it's not a script that any `GameObject` needs to run - and that's all Unity cares about. This is because it would be inefficient to look at any scripts that no `GameObject` needs.